# How to prevent the keyboard layout from changing?

Tags: keyboard

I'm using a standard USB keyboard with my MacBook, added a custom keyboard layout (in `Library/Keyboard Layouts`) and it works fine, but mac OS keeps switching back to the default layout after a few minutes.

**update**: I just noticed that it switches when I focus the Microsoft Outlook App. Strange. Sadly setting the language of outlook to English doesn't solve that.

I tried deleting the file `Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` (as suggested in similar questions) but it didn't help.

I'm currently running Catalina 10.15.3

[image]

Comment: I've had a similar issue with my custom keyboard layout. I don't really know what actually fixed it, I just tried exporting the layout (from Ukulele, which I used to edit it) a couple of times until one of them worked and "stuck". Sorry, I can't remember what I might have changed in between tries.

Comment: Assume you are not accidentally hitting the keyboard shortcut for switching layouts, Control + Space?

Comment: @TomGewecke turns out that shortcut was disabled for me. But at least now I can switch back quickly to my preferred layout

Answer (score 1):

update: I just noticed it happens with other programs too (for example mac OS' own Notes app) :(

I consider this is a weird quirk of Microsoft Outlook. See here for more details: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac/disable-automatically-switch-keyboard-to-match/717be469-2267-483b-9d66-7f9e77fac01e

I guess I'll use the Outlook Webapp from now on *sigh*